# Upload file to s3 with custom response to client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to upload a file to s3 and then have lambda generate id, date.
I then want to return this data back to the client. 
I want to avoid generating id and date on the client for security reasons.

Currently, I am trying to use API Gateway which invokes a lambda to upload into s3. However, I am having problems setting this up. I know that this is not a preferred method.

Is there another way to do this without writing my own web server. (I would like to use lambda).

If not, how can I configure my API Gateway method to support file upload to lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options here:

1. Use API Gateway as an AWS Service Proxy to S3
2. Use API Gateway to invoke a Lambda function, which uses the AWS SDK to upload to S3

In either case, you will need to base64 encode the file content before calling API Gateway, and POST it in the request body.

We don't currently have any documentation on this exact use case but I would refer you to the [S3 API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APIRest.html) and [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) docs for more information. If you have any specific questions we'd be glad to help.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: To my knowledge AWS Service Proxy will essential work like using the aws sdk to upload to s3 which does not work for my use case as I need to run custom server code and return it to the client. Correct me if I am wrong. The second option seems correct, but I have read that lambda is not designed to handle file uploads but rather is a simple event based service. Is there a disadvantage to provisioning a lot of memory for a lambda function to handle this traffic compared to a web app on ec2. My files will roughly be 10mb of data.

Comment: API Gateway currently limits payload size to 10MB so may not be the best fit for this use-case. You may want to follow up with Lambda (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=186) to discuss further options.

Comment: I believe a Lambda func will time-out before large files have finished uploading. Better to upload to S3 and have that upload event trigger a Lambda function to be run. Though you'd need your client to make the call after the upload was completed to get the id and date.

Comment: I also need an answer to this... I want to return a custom response to the client that's uploading to S3.